# How to use the Output of one SQL Statement in another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following statement:

```
select region_id from regions
where region_name = 'Europe'
```

I need the Output from this in the following statement where 'bla' is:

```
select count(*) from countries
where region_id = 'bla'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You changed the query on us! It started off as `distinct *` and now is `count(*)` hence why all the answers are out of synch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the [IN clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm)

```
select distinct * from countries
where region_id IN (select region_id from regions
where region_name = 'Europe')
```

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries to the rescue!

```
select distinct * 
from countries
where region_id=(select top 1 ir.region_id 
                 from regions ir
                 where ir.region_name = 'Europe' )
```

Alternatively, you can use `in` and give it a list of items returned from your query.

Comment: Would you look at that, they haven't added a limit... I've been spoiled with MSSQL.

Comment: I would still stick with MSSQL though.

Answer (score 2):

Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM COUNTRIES c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                 FROM REGIONS r
                WHERE r.region_id = c.region_id
                  AND r.region_name = 'Europe')
```

My preference is to use EXISTS rather than IN because:

- `IN` in Oracle has a limit of 1,000 values
- `EXISTS` allows you to match on more than one column if necessary
- `EXISTS` returns true on the first match, which can be faster than IN/etc depending on needs

Most mistake `EXISTS` as a correlated subquery, but it executes differently & doesn't evaluate the `SELECT` clause - you can test using:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM COUNTRIES c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1/0
                 FROM REGIONS r
                WHERE r.region_id = c.region_id
                  AND r.region_name = 'Europe')
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your reasons for preferring `EXISTS` over `IN` are entirely valid. The limit on 1,000 values with `IN` is only when comparing to an expression list and not for a subquery, `IN` will work with more than one column although the syntax is a little clumsy, and `IN` and `EXISTS` will often use the same execution plan if possible